# Use jQuery to load HTML from external file at absolute path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to load the content of an external HTML file into my current HTML template.

The problem I'm running into is that the content I want to load is not local, and it's not at a URL. The file is on a central storage directory that I can access while connected to a VPN. In other words, if all my local files are within `/Users/username/...`, then this file is at `/central_directory/absolute/path/to/file.html`.

I can access the file at `/central_directory/absolute/path/to/file.html` from the Terminal or at `file:///central_directory/absolute/path/to/file.html` from within my browser.

However, when I try to load the file using the jQuery `.load()` function, I get a 404 not found error:

> Not Found: /central_directory/absolute/path/to/file.html
>
> [15/Jul/2018 19:04:22] "GET /central_directory/absolute/path/to/file.html HTTP/1.1"
>   404 2257

My guess is that it's not looking in the right place for the file (e.g. it is looking at 
`http://mywebsite/central_directory/absolute/path/to/file.html`), but I don't know if this is an accurate guess, or how to test.

---

**Code:**

Here is the jQuery script, in the `head` of my current template:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var filename = "file:///central_directory/absolute/path/to/file.html"
        $("#includedContent").load(filename);
    });
</script>
```

and the HTML in the template:

```
<div id="includedContent"></div>
```

Simple enough, right?

I have also tried other syntax, with the same 404 error occurring.

Comment: Browsers restricts this by default. Imagine any website can access your local files. It would be a security risk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `.load()` *requires* an HTTP connection (so a `GET` or `POST` request) for javascript.

This is the fortunate result of the fact that you cannot load a javascript resource in the same way you can navigate to a `file://` path in your browser or terminal ('fortunate' because it prevents anybody from accessing *any* file on your computer).

The only real way to get around this is by having the local file proxied through a web server to your browser (so you'll need to have control over the server implementation). If you have an existing web server stack (like [PHP](http://www.php.net/), [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/), [Ruby](https://rubyonrails.org/), etc) you can very likely do this, but it ultimately depends on what it is.

Comment: Ah, so I was misunderstanding the nature of `.load()`, then. I thought it could be used to access file data in a similar way to how the `src` of an `img` tag works.

Thanks for this clarification - I will look into other options!

Comment: I'm afraid so, javascript resource loading works differently to that like the `src` of an `img` tag (as a security measure).